# application push certificat was expired, i don't have access to certificat

Tags: ios, certificate, apple-push-notifications, push

my compagny buy a application from another account, recently certificate push expired and push doesn't work anymore on version on the store, when i access to apple developper i can't find certificat linked to the current application

i think the certificates is keepen on the original account witch publish the application

we cannot have access to old account

what options we have to update certificat ? 
we had to create new certificat an push a new version on the store inevitably ?

thank you for your answers

Answer (score 0):

I have found answer on the apple documentation

https://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/deved688524f

Associated client SSL certificates for push notifications aren’t transferred. If the app uses Apple Push Notifications service (APNs), the recipient needs to create a client SSL certificate using the recipient’s developer account to reenable it.

Hope it will helps someone